# Ember.JS data model: Filtering a computed property

Tags: ember.js

I have an Ember data model `logger` defined as below:

```
import DS from 'ember-data';
import EmberObject, { computed } from '@ember/object';
export default DS.Model.extend({

    someAttribute: DS.hasMany('attr'),
    test: computed('someAttribute.[]', function(){
        return this.get('someAttribute').filterBy('description', 'some value');        
    })
});
```

The above model gets passed as `logger` variable from the controller into my component template. In my template:

```
{{#if logger.test}}    
    <h1> Testing </h1>
    {{log logger.test.description }}
{{/if}}
```

It seems like the `logger.test` in the template is always false. In the same template if I add the following:

```
{{#each logger.someAttribute as |t|}}
    {{t.description}}
{{/each}}
```

I can see all the values being enumerated. Not sure what I am missing? Any assistance would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Okay, I figured out. Turns out models return promises and the `if` statement doesn't handle promise well enough. The right way to do this would be to return a `DS.promiseArray` from the computed property and then everything works like a charm:

```
return DS.PromiseArray.create({
            promise: this.get('someAttribute').then(logs => {return logs.filterBy('description')})
        });
```

Acknowledgements: https://emberigniter.com/guide-promises-computed-properties/

Comment: ["While working with relationships it is important to remember that they return promises."](https://guides.emberjs.com/release/models/relationships/#toc_relationships-as-promises)

Answer (score 1):

I don't exactly understand what you're trying to achieve, but I would either

1. Load the `DS.hasMany('thing', {async: false})` and make sure they are included in the store. (See https://embermap.github.io/ember-data-storefront/latest/). If the relationship is set to `async: false` when it's accessed, it's accessed synchronously, so there is no issues with promises.
2. Using ember-concurrency can help manage the loading of the records and displaying them on the page.